# Reusing setter in model class

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got model class which I use to query a database. It all works there's no problem with it. I'm now trying to smarten up the code in my model class. Here is the code

```
class HumanFilter {
  double age, maxAge, minAge, weight, minWeight, maxWeight, tall, minTall, maxTall, waist, minWaist, maxWaist;

set setMaxAge(String s) {
  if (s != null) {
    double parsed = double.tryParse(s) != null ? double.parse(s) : maxAge;
    minAge = minAge != null && parsed != null
        ? parsed <= minAge && minAge != 0 ? parsed - 1 : minAge
        : null;
    maxAge = parsed;
    age = parsed != null ? null : age;
  } else {
    maxAge = null;
  }
}

set setMinAge(String s) {
if (s != null) {
  double parsed = double.tryParse(s) != null ? double.parse(s) : minAge;
  minAge = parsed;
  maxAge = maxAge != null && parsed != null
      ? parsed >= maxAge ? parsed + 1 : maxAge
      : null;
  age = parsed != null ? null : age;
} else {
  minAge = null;
}
}

set setAge(String s) {
if (s != null) {
  double parsed = double.tryParse(s) != null ? double.parse(s) : age;
  age = parsed != null ? parsed : age;
  minAge = parsed != null ? null : minAge;
  maxAge = parsed != null ? null : maxAge;
} else {
  age = null;
}
}
// another setters for the rest of the parameters which are same as the code above
}
```

The setters for the rest of the parameters are exactly the same as the setters I have provided for age. For example setter for weight is the same as for age setter but sets minWeight, maxWeight and weight instead of minAge, maxAge and age. Same with minTall and minAge and so on.

I thought to create a 3 methods which would take min, max and nominal values and return list or map of 3 values which I could then assign in setter method, but then I've also noticed that min and max setters are almost identical so that could perhaps be reused as well. I just can not find a decent way to reuse (smarten up) the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to factorize this duplicate would be to extract the min/max/current values in a class:

```dart
class Interval {
  double min;
  double max;
  double current;
}
```

This means that instead of `setMinAge`+`setMaxAge`+..., you would just have one of these on `Interval`:

```dart
class Interval {
  double min;
  double max;
  double current;

  set setMax(String s) {
    if (s != null) {
      var parsed = double.tryParse(s) != null ? double.parse(s) : max;
      min = min != null && parsed != null
          ? parsed <= min && min != 0 ? parsed - 1 : min
          : null;
      max = parsed;
      current = parsed != null ? null : current;
    } else {
      max = null;
    }
  }

  // setMin
  // setCurrent
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remi. I thought about this solution as well but not quite sure what is the best way to use it.. 1/ I can use Interval class in HumanFilter in all of my setters. Setters would take string and set each parameter (age, minAge, maxAge...) as they do now. Not exactly shorten up HF but passing data would stay unchanged 2/ Use Interval when passing data to HF.  Setters would take Interval. That would make HF very short because I would need only one setter for all ages one setter for all weights...  but I would need extra code when passing data to HF.. But I guess that is up to me then